# How can I embed a webpage in a GWT/GXT webapp?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am working to recreate (conceptually) a prototype I've written in Cappuccino in GWT/GXT. Cappuccino made it trivial to display an external webpage as part of the application by using a WebView.

However, I cannot find any way to do this with GWT/GXT. There is a HtmlContainer widget, but this seems to be intended for something else. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the url of a [ContentPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/ContentPanel.html)

e.g.

```
ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
panel.setUrl("http://www.url.com/page");
panel.setHeaderVisible(false);
panel.setBorders(false);
panel.setBodyBorder(false);
```

You can also do this for the GXT Window class too.

Comment: BTW, as of GXT 3.0, you need to use the [Frame widget](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/theme/base/client/frame/Frame.html) instead of ContentPanel.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the html-code and just want to render it use the "HTML"-widget. Form the [docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html)

> A widget that can contain arbitrary HTML. This widget uses a  element, causing it to be displayed with block layout.

If you want to display a different page e.g. stackoverflow.com in your webapp use the "frame" widget. From the [docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html):

> A widget that wraps an IFRAME element, which can contain an arbitrary web site.

Comment: It's the latter one, so thanks for your pointer; this works now.