# WordPress and GWT

Tags: java, wordpress, gwt, blogs

Any ideas on how to integrate WordPress into a GWT application?

I would like to create a blog page into a GWT application. Using WordPress would save me from creating a blogging system from scratch. Redirecting users to a blog hosted by WordPress (think myblog.wordpress.com) is not an option. I want to keep users inside my website.

Or, is there any blogging system (other than WordPress) that would integrate nicely with GWT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a RIA framework. You can pretty much do anything you want.

There are many options for what you want to achieve.

One propable solution would be to add a **com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame** Widget - which provides GWT with an IFrame - wherever you want inside your application. From the MVP perspective this could mean a new View consisting (maybe even extending) the frame. You could even POST the login credentials used to log in to your GWT application. Then you can load the view inside any class that emplements the HasWidgets interface.

You could do the same thing with a DialogBox.

Another probable solution would be to use something like www.mysitename.com for the GWT application and www.mysitename.com/blog as the wordpress site folder and redirect your users there using the anchor widget provided by GWT.

The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you mean with "integrate":) but this question/aswers might be worth checking for you:
[How can I embed a webpage in a GWT/GXT webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185386/how-can-i-embed-a-webpage-in-a-gwt-gxt-webapp)